# Error occurring when Entity State is modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to test a WCF Web Service  with a shopping cart.  The method below basically receives a list of CartLine and subtracts all the products added to the shopping cart from the database. Then it sends a message either processed or if the inventory is insufficient then an order cancellation message.

```
public string Deliver(List<CartLine> cartLine)
        {
            string strOut = null;
            StartPurchase();

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session["TransactionStarted"]))
            {
                //Traverse the cart line
                for (int i = 0; i < cartLine.Count; i++)
                {
                    //for each product in the cart line decrease inventory
                    if (cartLine[i].Product.Stock > 0)
                    {
                        //here decreasing inventory
                        (cartLine[i].Product.Stock) -= (cartLine[i].Quantity);

                             //Advice that entity has changed
                            db.Entry(cartLine[i].Product).State = EntityState.Modified; //offending line
                            db.SaveChanges();

                       strOut = "Order Processed!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       strOut =  "Order cancelled, Stock missing!";

                    }
                }

               return strOut;
            }
            else
            {
                return m_cartSessionNotStartedStr;
            }
        }
```

All things work fine if I add the same kind of product to the cart. As soon as I mix products, however,  then I get this error:

**Attaching an entity of type 'X’ failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.**

This error occurs at the point when saving the changes (see offending line above). While I understand that I should attach the  entity I am not sure how to proceed in this case when it is a list of product lines.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You must check if an entity with the same key is already tracked by the context or not. If entity tracked, modify that entity instead of attaching the current one:

```
var trackedEntity = context.Products.Find(cartLine[i].Product.Id);
context.Entry(trackedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(cartLine[i].Product);
context.Entry(trackedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could load the products in to the context prior.  That way the entity will be modified and not added.

Comment: mean within the method or somewhere else? and why does it occur only when the products are different?

Comment: What does your context actually have on it at this point, in terms of loaded data? Sorry, in answer to your question.  The method will be fine if it is used just here, you might want to widen the scope though.

Comment: By the way what does WFC mean.

Comment: it depends of the products that are being purchased I guess. Nothing if there is nothing in the cartline list or whatever is passed with the cartLine list. I am not sure if I understand your question though...

Comment: Sorry I meant WCF was a typo. It is a web service really

Comment: Ok so we now have a disconnected context and have to replay state on the server.  Basically we are going to have to build up the context and apply changes afterwards. Its a while since I've done this and I cant recall exactly an example, Ill have to look it up.  My resource will be DbContext by Julie Lerman a must read for this kind of strategy.

Comment: @brumScourse Thank you anyway... I think it has to do with attaching first the entity somehow. I am trying like this   db.Products.Attach(cartLine[i].Product);

Comment: That seems reasonable, are there any child entities off of product?  Their state  may be being tracked incorrectly. Anyway I think the guy above has come to our rescue! Sorry I couldnt have helped more.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure your problem is that there are objects with the same primary key but different reference in your object graph.

Comment: I see from the error that there is something wrong with the primary keys but how to fix this issue?

Comment: That’s a very common problem when using WCF and EntityFramework. Mostly this happens when you try to save an object graph that is built with objects from multiple previous WCF calls. Simplified: 1. get all products with suppliers included 2. Get all suppliers. 3. Change the supplier of any Product to a supplier from the second service call. 4. If any Product has the same supplier you now have 2 supplier with the same key but different reference in your product list. Could also be a missing (IsReference = true) on your DataContract.

Answer (score 1):

As brumScouse correctly said, you should load the products from the database prior to modifying them. But not only because in that case you're modifying attached products (so you don't have to manage their states yourself anymore) but also to make sure you're modifying *fresh* quantities. There may have been considerable time between fetching the products to the view and finally decreasing their quantities in the database. A concurrent user may have done the same in between.

I would fetch the products as follows:

```
// Fetch the products in the cartLines in one query
var productIds = cartLine.Select(c => c.Product.ProductId).ToList();
var dbProducts = db.Products.Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.ProductId));
```

And then in your loop:

```
var dbProduct = db.Products.Find(cartLine[i].Product.ProductId);
if (dbProduct.Stock > 0)
    dbProduct.Stock -= cartLine[i].Quantity;
```

`Find` will get a `Product` from the local collection.

One important point: make sure you implement optimistic concurrency to make sure that not two concurrent users will decrease the same `Product`'s stock in the small amount of time they're fetched from the database and modified and saved.